# Rings (integral domain and fields)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

True or false:

(1) Every integral domain is a field

(2) every field is an integral domain

(3) the ring $\mathbb Z$ is a field.

(4) the ring $\mathbb Z/(17)$ is a field.

(5)The set  $\{[0], [2], [4]\}$ is a subring of $\mathbb Z/(6)$

So I am having a little trouble with the whole concept of rings.  I know the definition of field, integral domain, ring ect., but I am just having trouble applying it.  I made up these questions based off the lecture notes just to maybe help me out.  If anyone can shed a little insight I would appreciate it.
My thoughts: 
1-false
2-true
3-false
4-true
5-false
Again not sure on the answers of interpreting them.  Just going by what I understood in lecture.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Why do you think you're having trouble?

Comment: @seaturtles As the OP has said,  he/she is having trouble with applying the concepts.

Comment: @Sanath And I asked why OP believes that.

Comment: Honestly its just the way they talk about the "identity" of a ring being 1 or 0.  Or how to find the identity. and just applying the definition of a ring in reference to the definition of a field or an integral domain.  The definition just isint dumbed down enough I guess for me to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Okay, how about this. Explain in your question how you got your answers.

Comment: and theres where my knowledge is not enough... wouldnt say they were guesses but looking at my notes I just tried to kind of connect the dots. explaining it is what I cannot do. For one I know just from my notes that it is false but cant think of an example to disprove it. number 2/3/4 are the same way. 5 you can multiply the parts of the subring to get something that is not in Z6 so that was my reasoning why its not a subring.

Comment: maybe an example disproving it would help? I am trying to find one.

Comment: @D-Man : You "know from your notes" but can't say why? Contrary to what you said, the set in (5) is closed under multiplication, so that does not prevent the set from being a ring. Let's stick with (5) until you get it. What *other* axioms does the set need to satisfy?

Comment: I see it in my notes but it doesn't make sense.  It has to be closed under addition, multiplication, 0(R) has to be in S, and if a is in S, then the solution of a + x = 0(R) is in S.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake the first term in the "subset" is 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

(1) False, consider $\mathbb{Z}$.

(2)True, a field is an integral domain in which every element is a unit.

(3) False, check the elements that have inverses (HINT: There are only two elements that are units in $\mathbb{Z}$)

(4)True, you know that it is an integral domain, now check that every element is a unit.

(5)See if you can work this one out on your own.

Hope this helps!